# Loading jQuery into Grunt.js using the grunt-contrib-jasmine plugin

Tags: jasmine, gruntjs

I am trying to load jQuery into my tests using Grunt.js and the grunt-contrib-jasmine plugin. Here is a gist of my Gruntfile.js and I've referenced jQuery in the jasmine.options.vendor array as the [documentation](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-jasmine) suggests.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4751371

However, when I run a very simple test, it fails because jQuery isn't getting loaded:

```
describe('like module', function() {
    var $ul;

    beforeEach(function() {
        $ul = $('<ul><li class="no-results"></li></ul>');
    });

    it('should test the value of some numbers', function() {
        expect(9).toEqual(9);
    });

});
```

Any idea why?

Comment: You load jQuery via a CDN. Have you tried the same with a locally installed jQuery?

Comment: Ya it works when you use a local copy of jQuery. Kind of annoying but at least it works.

Comment: I think it's a bug, compare this issue: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine/issues/18

Comment: It would be useful to be able to do this though. I tried the grunt-contrib-jasmine-requirejs plugin and couldn't get it working either.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After having seen the link by @ludder, I have changed my Jasmine task config to:

```
jasmine: {
  src: ['./someFile.js'],
    options: {
      specs: 'test/*Spec.js',
      keepRunner : false,
      vendor: 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'
    }
  }
```

The key is to use `http` and **not** `https`.

Tests are passing now.