# How do I use Jasmine to test a text length counter?

Tags: jquery, jasmine, phantomjs, gruntjs

I'm having a little difficulty with Jasmine. I'm using the `grunt-contrib-jasmine` plugin with Grunt to automate testing through PhantomJS. I have [already successfully loaded jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803583/loading-jquery-into-grunt-js-using-the-grunt-contrib-jasmine-plugin) so I'm not having any problems with that. The main problem is that I can't get my counter to count down when the test has run. Here's `base.js`, the script where the counter runs:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    "use strict";
    $('.text').keyup(function()
    {
        $('.count').text(60 - $(this).val().length);
    });
});
```

where `.text` is the input field and `.count` is a span where the counter goes. And here's the spec for this file:

```
describe("Main JS file", function() {

    "use strict";

    var $text, $count;

    beforeEach(function() {
        $count = $('<span class="count">60</span>');
        $text = $('<input type="text" maxlength="60" class="text">');
    });

    it("displays a count of the characters in the text box", function() {
        $text.val('Hello, World!');
        $text.trigger('keyup');
        expect($count.text()).toEqual(47);
    });

});
```

Here's the config in `Gruntfile.js`:

```
jasmine: {
    tests: {
        src: ['assets/js/base.js'],
        options: {
            specs: 'spec/base.js',
            vendor: ['assets/js/jquery.js']
        }
    }
},
```

When I run `grunt jasmine` I only get this error:

```
$ grunt jasmine
Running "jasmine:tests" (jasmine) task
Testing jasmine specs via phantom
x
Main JS file:: displays a count of the characters in the text box: failed
  Expected '60' to equal 47. (1)
1 spec in 0.001s.
>> 1 failures
```

Would really appreciate any help with this. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**: Now using jasmine-jquery, I can see that the event has fired but the counter text is still not being updated!

```
it("displays a count of the characters in the text box", function() {

    spyOnEvent($text, 'keyup');
    $text.val('Hello, World!');
    $text.keyup();
    expect('keyup').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn($text);
    expect($count).toHaveText('47');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you try to bind the key event before the element is rendered in your `before` function. One idea is to refactor your code so you can run the function that binds the event in your test.

```
function addKeyEvent(){
 $('.text').keyup(function()
    {
        $('.count').text(60 - $(this).val().length);
    });
}

$(document).ready(addKeyEvent);
```

And in your test, call the function after creating the elements:

```
describe("Main JS file", function() {

"use strict";

var $text, $count;

beforeEach(function() {
    $count = $('<span class="count">60</span>').appendTo('body');
    $text = $('<input type="text" maxlength="60" class="text">').appendTo('body');
    addKeyEvent()
});

it("displays a count of the characters in the text box", function() {
    $text.val('Hello, World!');
    $text.trigger('keyup');
    expect($count.text()).toEqual('47');
});

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still returns the same error (I also tried var addKeyEvent = function() { } and function addKeyEvent() {} to no avail). Perhaps the problem is with the event trigger itself? I'm not very experienced with any of this so I'm not sure, but the problem seems to be that the counter is not getting updated when the test is run. (expected 60 to be 47).

Comment: Ok, you have to add the DOM elements to the body, and you have to test again `"47"` as the returning value is a string not a number.

Comment: Did that, got this:   `Expected '<span class="count">60</span>' to have text '47'. (2)
1 spec in 0.001s.
>> 1 failures`

Comment: ok, there was a minor error in my code, trying it with http://tryjasmine.com/ and it works for me